# How to get PostgreSQL hashes in Phoenix's Ecto models?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to define a PostgreSQL-Hash type field in my Ecto model but I'm not sure how to do it. I haven't found an explicit guide on this topic and I'm assuming it's somewhere hidden in here: http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html

Has anyone the definite guide to do PostgreSQL-Hash fields in Ecto?

Comment: Maybe you have to provide an `Ecto.Type` implementation to accommodate your needs?

Comment: Could be. Has anyone done this before and wants to share? :-) In the meantime I will experiment with this.

Comment: There is `The map type` section in the docs you attached a link to, have you tried to use it?

Comment: Yes that's it. Thanks! I'm coming from Rails so I think I got confused by the naming.

Comment: @JustMichael You should post that as an answer so others can find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As JustMichael stated, the answer is the `:map` type.

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.authors (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('authors_id_seq'::regclass),
  settings HSTORE,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  inserted_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
);
```

The Ecto model:

```
defmodule Nexus.Author do
  use Nexus.Web, :model

  schema "authors" do
    field :settings, :map
    timestamps
  end
end
```

Now I can get access the settings `Nexus.Repo.get(Author, some_id).settings` and get a map in return.